# Extracting double quotes out of cell using formula

Tags: excel, formula, quotes

I have a little problem. There is a string that is below on cell A4

> Following":"Animals

I want to extract the word 'Animals' using the prior string 'Following":"'

But before this, if I do

> =find("Following"&""":""",$A4)

I am getting an error. Please help me with getting this formula work. I can make the rest work!

Edit: There is few other colons so I cannot look for colon alone

Comment: Are you sure that's what your cell contains because I get a result of 1 with that formula?

Comment: `=FIND("Following:"":""",$A4)`. But out of curiosity, what do you mean by *"I can make the rest work!"*. Maybe there is a much simpler solution to your needs?

Comment: Anyway, can't you just look for the colon?

Comment: @JvdV I think you have an extra `:` in your formula.

Comment: I cant look for colon, as there is many other incidents of colon within that string

Comment: Ah yes, matter of removing the 1st for OP @ScottCraner.